# Clang AST for a template method of a template class

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

I have the following piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  template <typename U>
  void bar() const;
};

[[template <typename T>]]
template <typename U>
void Foo<T>::bar() const
{
}
```

Dumping the AST tree for method `foo` gives the following for the method definition (irrelevant details were removed for clarity):

```
`-FunctionTemplateDecl <line:10:1, line:14:1> col:11:14 bar
 |-TemplateTypeParmDecl <line:10:11, col:20> col:20 typename depth 1 index 0 U
 `-CXXMethodDecl <line:9:1, line:14:1> line:11:14 bar 'void () const'
  `-CompoundStmt <line:12:1, line:14:1>
```

I cannot figure out how to find location of `template <typename T>` part (the one which is in `[[...]]` block). I didn't able to find anything related in clang AST API. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question. Some clues: as can be seen in the [example of the return of `RedeclarableTemplateDecl::getInstantiatedFromMemberTemplate()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RedeclarableTemplateDecl.html#adb241cd6ce45e09c495f1875adc5f106) `FunctionTemplateDecl` contains both template parameter list. Moreover, `FunctionTemplateDecl` derives from `TemplateDecl`, which exposes its `TemplateParameterList*` member `TemplateParams` via [`getTemplateParameters()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TemplateDecl.html#a7f8b28a5d4a680cea9dc71c5c886a7f3). ...

Comment: However, afaics `getTemplateParameters()` only returns the template parameter list for the _deepest_ template parameter list; see e.g. the description of [`TemplateParameterList::getDepth()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TemplateParameterList.html#ac5c2012bf7869ee8aadbdfbb98ab57af), which mentions _"Get the depth of this template parameter list in the set of template parameter lists. "_, which I interpret as us wanting to find the _set of template parameter lists_ somehow. ...

Comment: ... I guess we somehow wants to find a [`MultiLevelTemplateArgumentList`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1MultiLevelTemplateArgumentList.html) for the original template declaration.

Comment: Thank you for you comments. I will continue researching clang sources having these classes in mind. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for my own question so posting the answer. Hopefully it maybe helpful for someone else.

It's possible to get location information for outer template parameters using `getNumTemplateParameterLists()` and `getTemplateParameterList()` methods of `DeclaratorDecl` class.
See [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclaratorDecl.html) for details.